# Cannot visit Wordpress normally

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

[image]

As you can see, it gives me a weird view. I use apache+php5+mysql for my wordpress, and everything seems to work right during installation of Wordpress. But it just gives me such a strange scene.

Has anyone seen similar problem as I do? When could be the reason for this?

Comment: Can you visit it strangely?

Comment: @aguyfromhere I see what you did there... :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure without visiting the site, but it looks like you didn't add index.php to DirectoryIndex in your httpd.conf file (for Apache, or whatever the equivalent is in whichever server you're using)

Comment: That's exactly where the problem is! Although I've solved it, but still thank you~

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure - pic resolution is low but it looks like the directory contents. make sure php is (a) installed (b) enabled on the directory (c) after you make changes to the server config, restart it (d) php files are set to execute php interpreter

Comment: I've solved it...it turns out that I need to add "DirectoryIndex index.php" to Apache's config file to make it recognize it. Thanks anyway~